# No virtual keyboard appear when click input field in Android

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

In this jQuery Mobile/Phonegap app, I have an input field which works fine on iOS, but when deployed it on android, when I click the inputfield, there has no virtual keyboard pop up on 
Android devices.

What's the potential issue?

```
 <input type="search" name="search" data-style="mini" data-theme="d" placeholder="Search by: name" class="round" value="" onchange="app.appRouter.trigger('clicked')"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that, I used data-tap-toggle="false" in the div wrap it, it caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="search" id="openkeybord" name="search" data-style="mini" data-theme="d" placeholder="Search by: name" class="round" value="" onchange="app.appRouter.trigger('clicked')"/> 

$("#openkeybord").on('click', function() {
   $("#openkeybord").focus();
});
```